# Else if Ignored

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have an if else statement:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x="";
var myProb = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
if (myProb<0.3)
  {
  x="Good morning";
  }
else if (myProb<0.6)
  {
  x="Good day";
  }
else
  {
  x="Good evening";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

The "if" and the "else" bit are executed, but the "else if" bit is completely left out.
"Good Day" NEVER happens!

Why is this?
I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`myProb` is only ever going to be `0` or `1`, so `else if` will never be a condition which is met.

---

My assumption is you want decimal places between `0` and `1`. In which case remove `Math.Round()`:

```
var myProb = Math.random();
```

Comment: Yes, you are SO right.  Makes sense (no idea why I didn't see that). It's all working great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

the result of `Math.round(Math.random() * 1)` can only be 0 or 1 due to the Math.round, hence why you are never going inside the middle if.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.round(Math.random() * 1);` can only produce 0 or 1. 0 will fall for "Good morning" and 1 for "Good evening".

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
if (myProb<0.3)
  {
  x="Good morning";
  }
```

is true before the

```
else if (myProb<0.6)
  {
  x="Good day";
  }
```

and `math.round` produce 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100
```

Or just

```
Math.random()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That's it. It works great now!

Answer (score -1):

Changing your function a bit to take myProb as a parameter gives:

```
function myFunction(myProb)
{
var x="";
if (myProb<0.3)
  {
  x="Good morning";
  }
else if (myProb<0.6)
  {
  x="Good day";
  }
else
  {
  x="Good evening";
  }
console.log(x);
}

myFunction(0.4)
```

Doing this in Chrome prints `Good day` to the console. Your problem seems to be that you are rounding off the value `Math.random()`. Separating the code like this makes it clearer where your error lies.

Comment: -1: it is not about being unlucky. The problem is with rounding a random number.

Comment: @freakish Yeah you are righ. I saw that now but was a bit quick with the answere :). I think my answer now shows that there is nothing wrong with the if-elseif-else part of the code...

Comment: Haha yeah and I can confirm that! Thanks everyone, you understood correctly! Rounding decimals was the problem :P!